# Semigroup of bit-string substitutions - any pointers?

Tags: substitution, semigroups, bit-strings

Consider a pair $s=(s_0,s_1)$ of bit-strings (strings of 0s and 1s). Let $s$ act on a bit-string $b$ by replacing every $0$ in $b$ by $s_0$ and every $1$ in $b$ by $s_1$. Then the set $S$ of all such 'substitutions' forms a semigroup.

I am interested in finding out various properties of this semigroup. Surely the structure this semigroup has been studied before. Any pointers?

Some questions about this semigroup:

- Are there any other automorphisms except for the identity and interchanging 0 and 1? (Probably no, but how do you prove this?)
- Is there a proper subsemigroup of $S$ isomorphic to $S$?questions?
- What are the commutative subsemigroups? One example is the semigroup of substitutions of the form (00…0,11…1) which is isomorphic to $(\mathbf{N}^2,\cdot)$.
- The cancellation property does not hold in general. Is there a subsemigroup for which it holds?

Any information, pointers to papers, websites, … are welcome.

Comment: I don't get what the elements of your semigroup are. Is this $b$ fixed and $s\in S$ is a pair $s = (s_0,s_1)$? So that for $r,s,t\in S$ we have $rs = t$ if $t$ yields the same substitution of $b$ as first substituting via $s$ and then via $t$?

Comment: You are correct. If we denote action on bit-strings by 'powers', we find $b^{rs} = (b^r)^s$. In fact, it is also easily seen that $(rs)_0=r_0^s$ and $(rs)_1=r_1^s$.

Comment: The bit-string $b$ is not fixed but only serves to show how the elements of the semigroup act on bit-strings in general. The semigroup $S$ is a set of actions, i.e., maps of bit-strings to bit-strings.

Comment: I think there are more automorphisms. Reversing $s_0$ and $s_1$ is one, I guess. For example $(1011,100) \mapsto (1101,001)$. Notice it's different from your automorphisms. Proof idea: Look at $r,s \in S$. Let $\tilde{r},\tilde{s}$ be the  reversed $r$ and $s$. Write $r_0 = x_1\dots x_n$ where $x_i = 0$ or $1$. Now $(rs)_0 = r_0^s = x_1(s)\dots x_n(s)$. Reversing $(rs)_0$ yields $x_n(\tilde{s})\dots x_1(\tilde{s})$. This is the same as $(\tilde{r}\tilde{s})_0$, if I'm not mistaken. The same applies to $r_1$. So this is a morphism. Applying it twice yields the identity, so it's an automorphism.

Comment: Quick counterexample: $i = (0,1)$ is the identity (replace 0 by 0, replace 1 by 1). Your automorphism gives $\bar i = (1,0)$ which is not the identity. A semigroup automorphism must map an identity (neutral element) to an identity (neutral element).

Comment: Did not read your example fully and made the wrong assumption about what you meant by 'reversing'. My apologies.

Comment: @PhilippOtto Your example is I think correct. If you denote the reversal operation of bit-strings by $\rho$, then your automorphism maps $s$ onto the action $\rho s \rho$, and because $\rho^2 = 1$ we find, $(\rho s \rho )(\rho t \rho) = \rho s t \rho$. If we were to extend the semigroup $S$ with $\rho$, then your automorphism becomes an inner automorphism of the larger semigroup that fixes $S$.

Comment: I guess a semigroup automorphism doesn't have to map the identity to the identity. Interchanging $0$ and $1$ doesn't for example. Fixing the identity would be a monoid morphism.

Comment: It seems like $S$ is the following semi group (it's even a monoid). Let $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$. Now create the free semi group over $\Sigma$, that is the semi group $\Sigma^{+}$ containing all finite combinations of elements in $\Sigma$. So this is the set of all finite strings. Concatenation is the operation. For example $10011 \cdot 1010 = 100111010$. Now your $S$ is the set of semi group endomorphisms on $\Sigma^{+}$. (you can check that every $s\in S$ is a semi group morphism and every such morphism defines an $s\in S$). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid#Endomorphisms

Comment: Thank you. A Google search on 'endomorphisms of the free monoid' yields quite a few papers, so I have the 'pointers' I asked for.